# How to turn observations to variable and summarise each value per variable condition

Tags: r, data-science, tidyverse, janitor

i have a dataset with diff columns/observations

see dataset below

| merchant | Status | Face value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | processing | 10 |
| b | processing | 5 |
| c | success | 40 |
| d | Transaction declined | 30 |
| e | success | 32 |
| f | pending | 21 |
| g | Transaction declined | 23 |
| h | Success | 45 |
| i | Transaction declined | 66 |
| j | success | 76 |
| k | pending | 87 |
| l | processing | 89 |

I want a situation where by i can transform the status column to variables and summarise the face value for each merchant

is it possible to use janitor package to summarise value instead of count?

just like in this case below that i use janitor package to summarise for count alone

This is my line of code to summarise count of transaction using janitor package

```
report_21st%>%
  tabyl(Merchant , Status)%>%
  adorn_totals("row")%>%
  adorn_percentages("row")%>%
  adorn_pct_formatting()%>%
  adorn_ns("front")
```

This is the outcome of the code below

| merchant | pending | processing | success | Success | Transaction declined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a 0 (0.0%) | 1(100.0%) | 0 (0.0%) | 0 (0.0%) |  | 0 (0.0%) |
| b 0(0.0%) | 1(100.0%) | 0 (0.0%) | 0 (0.0%) |  | 0 (0.0%) |
| c 0 (0.0%) | 0(0.0%) | 1 (100.0%) | 0 (0.0%) |  | 0 (0.0%) |
| d 0 (0.0%) | 0(0.0%) | 0 (0.0%) | 0 (0.0%) |  | 1 (100.0% |

So i want to do exactly the same thing for Value this time not count
you can suggest me any r package that can handle this or if i can also use janitor to handle value, and if it is a tidyverse or dplyr package please a sample code is requred.
please a line of code or sample of code would be well appreciated again

Plus im a biginner in r

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider` instead of `tabyl` and then use the `janitor` codes.

```
library(tidyr)
library(janitor)

report_21st %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Status, values_from = Face.value, values_fill = 0) %>%
  adorn_totals("row")%>%
  adorn_percentages("row")%>%
  adorn_pct_formatting()%>%
  adorn_ns("front")

# merchant   processing      success Transaction declined      pending     Success
#        a  10 (100.0%)   0   (0.0%)           0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%)  0   (0.0%)
#        b   5 (100.0%)   0   (0.0%)           0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%)  0   (0.0%)
#        c   0   (0.0%)  40 (100.0%)           0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%)  0   (0.0%)
#        d   0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%)          30 (100.0%)   0   (0.0%)  0   (0.0%)
#        e   0   (0.0%)  32 (100.0%)           0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%)  0   (0.0%)
#        f   0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%)           0   (0.0%)  21 (100.0%)  0   (0.0%)
#        g   0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%)          23 (100.0%)   0   (0.0%)  0   (0.0%)
#        h   0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%)           0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%) 45 (100.0%)
#        i   0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%)          66 (100.0%)   0   (0.0%)  0   (0.0%)
#        j   0   (0.0%)  76 (100.0%)           0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%)  0   (0.0%)
#        k   0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%)           0   (0.0%)  87 (100.0%)  0   (0.0%)
#        l  89 (100.0%)   0   (0.0%)           0   (0.0%)   0   (0.0%)  0   (0.0%)
#    Total 104  (19.8%) 148  (28.2%)         119  (22.7%) 108  (20.6%) 45   (8.6%)
```

**data**

```
report_21st <- structure(list(merchant = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h", "i", "j", "k", "l"), Status = c("processing", "processing", 
"success", "Transaction declined", "success", "pending", "Transaction declined", 
"Success", "Transaction declined", "success", "pending", "processing"
), Face.value = c(10L, 5L, 40L, 30L, 32L, 21L, 23L, 45L, 66L, 
76L, 87L, 89L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak Shah
I tried to run the code with another data set
but is given error 

Error: Can't convert <double> to <list>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates